# Is it possible for multiple users to access a Samba share concurrently?

Tags: samba, usb-storage

So I'm planning on mining Ethereum, and found that the blockchain is about 1 tb! None of my computers have the disk space to store this gargantuan blockchain. However I do have a 2 tb USB hard drive that could hold the entire blockchain easily. I'm planning on mounting the USB hard drive on an old computer that I recently installed Ubuntu on and then making it available to my other computers via a Samba share. This implies that multiple computers will be using the same blockchain on the Samba share concurrently, shared between my other computers, all of which will be mining Ethereum and using the USB hard drive Samba share for the centralized, single blockchain.

Would this work? If not are there any workarounds?

Comment: Probably not possible, as all computers will need to be able to update the shared file.

Comment: Access a Share, yes. Access the same file in that share, depends on the application and the file.  In this case, almost assuredly not.